# connection oracle 11g with java 8 (eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle11g

I can't import java.sql.*; because it said that this package is not accessible although I put ojdbc6 and also I tried ojdbc8 in the classpath but it isn't work;
[ I mention that I have oracle 11g and jdk 10 & eclipse 4 ]

Comment: Why does your title say "Java 8", but the text say "jdk 10"? Which is it? --- Actually, the error gives it away, it is not Java 8, but please don't ever give conflicting information like that when asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

How did you add your ojdbc driver ? A typical way is shown below:

First you need to right click your project and go for "Build Path" and go for "Configure build Path"

[image: Find the configure build path]

Then , in the "libraries" tab, click on the "Add External JARs" go to your ojdbc driver file to load it. 
[image: Add Ojdbc]

This is the typical way to load your ojdbc driver. Try first see whether it will help

Comment: *FYI:* Missing JDBC driver jar file would not cause `package is not accessible` error for `import java.sql.*;` since the `java.sql` package is built-in. This is a Java 9+ *modular* issue. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61313901/5221149).

Answer (score 0):

If your IDE (Eclipse) gives error:

```
The package java.sql is not accessible
```

Or if compiling using `javac` gives error:

```
test\Test.java:3: error: package java.sql is not visible
import java.sql.*;
           ^
  (package java.sql is declared in module java.sql, but module Test does not read it)
1 error
```

Then it is because your **Java 9+** project has a `module-info.java` file, i.e. your project is **modular**.

You need to add the following line to the `module-info.java` file:

```java
    requires java.sql;
```